# Simple trig problem-

Tags: trigonometry

I have this triangle, I need to find the angle at the $C$ corner.

[image: triangle]

What I tried:

$$\operatorname{tan} C=\frac23$$
$$C=\operatorname{arctan}\frac23$$
$$C\approx 33.69$$

However this is the wrong answer, what did I do wrong?

Comment: It's $\dfrac32$ , not $\dfrac23$

Comment: $tan C = {3 \over 2}$ not ${2 \over 3}$.

Comment: I think $56.31$ will do.

Comment: Okay thanks everyone, can one of you please post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost right, but the mnemonic is toa, not tao: you should divide $3$ by $2$.
So this is the correct calculation:
$$\text{tan } C=\frac32$$
$$C=\text{arctan} \frac32$$
$$C \approx 56^{\circ}$$

Comment: Although tao is equally important in mathematics.

Comment: @lemon you mean $2\pi?$