# Find the angle between the sides 4 and 7 in a right triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I need to solve the $B$ corner

[image: triangle]

What I've tried:

$$\operatorname{sin} B=\frac47$$
$$B=\operatorname{arcsin}\frac47$$
$$B=34.85$$

But that's not the right answer, can anyone help me find what I did wrong?

Comment: Is $\angle BAC = 90^{\circ}$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes, of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $\cos B=\frac 47$

Comment: What do you mean with the escaping of $\operatorname{cos}$

Comment: I had that too at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885521/renewcommand-tan-sin-renewcommand-arctan-arcsinsimple-trig-problem/885523) question, and as you can see, the links contains renewcommand-tan-sin-renewcommand-arctan-arcsin for some reason... I solved it with text{tan} and text{arctan}

Comment: @Leocrat: putting the backslash before it so the trig function comes out in the proper font. So putting sin between dollar signs gets $sin$, while putting \sin between dollar signs gets $\sin$  Normally one does not need the operatorname that you used, but something seems messed up.  Why do you have the renewcommand lines at the start?

Comment: Check the question code (try to edit it) and figure it out... I removed the "malicious" code based on [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page).

Comment: I think Leocrat has typed renewcommand{\cos}{\tan} with dollar signs in the title...

Comment: @RossMillikan. You typed "cos" instead of "\cos".

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I know.  The question redirected \cos to give me tan, so I stuck with cos

Comment: @RossMillikan. What does that mean ? Are there bad intentions here around ? I must confess that I was very surprized to make this comment to $you$ (since moreover I am almost blind !). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:  OP had some $\LaTeX$ that redefined \cos to come out tan.  I believe it has been removed now.  It was also in the question (from the same OP) linked in the second comment.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin B\neq \frac{4}{7}$

$\sin B=\frac{AC}{7}$

$AC=\sqrt{33}$  by pythagorean theorem.

Comment: I just fixed 2 minor typo's (\sinB changed to \sin B).